# Is it possible to "not mind" doing something, but still dislike it?

Tags: word-usage, idioms, sentence-usage

Usually when I hear people ask: "Do you mind doing [task]?", they are expecting one of two responses:

- "No, I don't mind." Which means I would like to do the task.
- "Yes, I do mind." Which means I would *not* like to do the task.

What if I am willing to do the task (I don't mind), but I would actively dislike doing it (I do mind)? Neither of the above responses seem to cover that middle ground.

How do I express my begrudging acceptance in this case?

Comment: "If I must" expresses begrudging acceptance. Note that "I don't mind" doesn't necessarily mean that you would *like* to do the task - that could be the case, or it could be that you have no feelings about it one way or the other. Or even that you have a mild dislike for the task but don't mind doing it anyway because of some benefit you get out of doing it.

Answer (score 2):

There's no *necessary* implication that "I don't mind" means you **want** to do the task.

If a couple had the following conversation:

> Wife - Honey, do you mind changing the baby's diaper?
>   Husband - No, I don't mind.

One could hardly assume that the husband **likes** changing diapers, only that he's willing to do it because he knows it must be done.

There's also no requirement that the answer include either "I don't mind" or "I do mind"...

If he wanted to tease his wife, he might add any number of variations:

> Again... ugh, I'll take care of it.
>   Do I have to?
>   Of course I mind... but I'll do it just for you.

There's tons of options and there's no reason to limit your response. If you want to say that you do mind but you'll do it any way, that's OK... though it's probably best done in a light-hearted manner.

Remember that "Do you mind" is a polite or indirect way of asking someone to do something, not always a question asking whether they actually mind or not.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use *if you insist*.

> I will answer this question *if you insist*.

Which asks for confirmation that the task really needs to be done, even though it might be difficult or unpleasant.